# Issue with creating a react app from vite, I can't find react as variant

Tags: reactjs, vite

[PS C:\Users\bryancheru\Desktop\CryptoVault\client>npm init vite@latest
√ Project name: ... ./
√ Current directory is not empty. Remove existing files and continue? ... yes
√ Select a framework: » React
? Select a variant: » - Use arrow-keys. Return to submit.

> TypeScript
> TypeScript + SWC
> JavaScript
> JavaScript + SWC

[with react in the variant](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VDUlN.png)

Comment: you should edit your question to explain what the problem is, format the error code properly and/or show the error screenshots (don't attach it as a link)